# Substitute vertical lines in Bash

Tags: bash, awk, gsub

I'm having a hard time finishing my script since there's this part which doesn't function the way I wanted it to be.

I have this line in my script:

```
cat /home/tmp/temp1.txt | awk '{gsub("~",RS);gsub("*",RS);print}' >  /home/tmp/temp.txt
```

It works fine, yes.
But when I do something like this:

```
cat /home/tmp/temp1.txt | awk '{gsub("|",RS);print}' >  /home/tmp/temp.txt
```

It's not working at all.
I wanted to change all my vertical bars into new line and yet I can't achieve it. Please help me with this. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do all the replacements in a single awk like this:

```
awk '{gsub(/[*~|]/, RS)} 1' /home/tmp/temp1.txt
```

Pipe is otherwise used for regex alternation that needs escaping. However inside the character class `[...]` pipe or asterisk need not be escaped as shown above.

It is also better to use `/.../` regex literal in `gsub` function instead of quoted string.

Comment: Just fyi that `awk '{gsub("\\|", RS)} 1'` OR `awk '{gsub(/\|/, RS)} 1'` OR `awk '{gsub(/[|]/, RS)} 1'`would work fine for just the pipe symbol.

Comment: Thanks for the info @anubhava.

Answer (score 1):

If you really only want to replace vertical bars with newlines, you can do that much more succinctly with `tr` which *translates* characters:

```
echo "hi|there|my|friend"   |    tr '|' '\n'
hi
there
my
friend
```

Or, if you are using a file:

```
tr '|' '\n'  < /home/tmp/temp.txt
```