# Change output field seperator on first row

Tags: awk

I have a file like this

```
name|age
Bob|30
Tom|50
Cindy|10
```

I want the first row to have a different seperator, "^".

```sh
awk 'NR==1 { gsub("|","^")1}1' f
```

But I keep getting

```
^n^a^m^e^|^a^g^e^
Bob|30
Tom|50
Cindy|10
```

Desired output is

```
name^age
Bob|30
Tom|50
Cindy|10
```

Comment: `awk 'NR==1 { gsub("[|]","^") }1' f`?

Comment: ah. that was it. Spent way too much time on that :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Substitute vertical lines in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369035/substitute-vertical-lines-in-bash)

Comment: Replace first `|` with `^` in complete file: `perl -0777 -pe 's/\|/^/' file`

Answer (score 5):

Your code with `gsub("|","^")` doesn't have special meta character `|` (used for alternation in regex) escaped hence it will match every position in input.

You may use this `awk` without involving any regex:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} FNR==1{OFS="^"; $1=$1; OFS=FS} 1' f
```

```
name^age
Bob|30
Tom|50
Cindy|10
```

**Details:**

- `FS="|"`: Sets `FS` as `|`
- `OFS="^"`: Sets `OFS` as `^`
- `$1=$1`: **Forces** `awk` to reformat each of the fields using `OFS`

Answer (score 3):

Like this :

```
awk -F'|' 'NR==1{print $1,$2;next}1' OFS='^' file
```

or a mix between [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava) response and mine:

```
awk -F'|' 'NR==1{$1=$1}1' OFS='^' file
```

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'FNR==1{sub(/\|/,"^")} 1' Input_file
```

Use `gsub` in place of `sub` in case of multiple occurrences needs to be changed.

```
awk 'FNR==1{gsub(/\|/,"^")} 1' Input_file
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `sed`:

```
sed '1 s/|/^/' ip.txt
```

- `1` address for the command, which is first line here
- `|` is not special, because by default `sed` uses BRE, see [this Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y) for BRE vs ERE differences
- use `s/|/^/g` if you can have multiple matches

Comment: Please add `g` as there might me multiple `|` in a row

Comment: @anubhava done.. I didn't use as sample had only one, but good idea to say so